# Sequence Points

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

I've looked in almost all popular C++ books. Is there a particular book that gives a good introduction about them? or is this a complier related topic instead of the language?

Edit: I've already seen the related FAQ questions.

Comment: Introduction about  almost all popular C++ books?

Comment: We have a Stack Overflow question dedicated to the topic of sequence points: [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Sequence points are definitely related to the language, and not just to the compiler. They are also a subtle aspect of the language, that even some experienced programmers do not understand fully; and they don't need to: the only times the precise semantics of sequence points matter are when you are writing obfuscated code. All in all, a natural omission for a programming book.